# Passing expression to find command not working

Tags: terminal, find, solaris

I tried the following command to list all the files which has /SL/src/ in its path

```
find * -type f -name '*/SL/src/*'
```

but it does not prints any thing even though there are files within the directory SL/src

Comment: That won't work, I am surprised that you do not get an error message (the GNU variant of `find` does warn and exit): the `-name` parameter defines a _name_ template, not a _path_ template. You are looking for files with `/SL/src/` in the _filename_!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use something like  that:

```
find * -type d -exec sh -c '
for i do
  [ "$(basename $i)" = src ] &&
  [ "$(basename $(dirname $i))" = SL ] &&
  find "$i" -type f ; done
' sh {} +
```

or simply:

```
find * -type f | grep /SL/src/
```